# c++ shared library fPIC or undefined library ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, ubuntu-16.04, fpic

I am trying to compile a code as a shared library (it compiles well on windows but I can't make it compiles on ubuntu 16.04).

If I try to compile "as on windows", I get the error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

so to compile the static libraries that are linked to my code, I added the -fPIC option (it seems to be by default on windows but not on linux but I am not sure):

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
```

and in my code, which is compiled using qmake I added:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
```

and now I get these errors:

```
itkGDCMImageIO.cxx:(.text+0xf9e) : undefined reference to « typeinfo for itk::MetaDataObjectBase »
itkGDCMImageIO.cxx:(.text+0xfb5) : undefined reference to « itk::MetaDataObject<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::GetMetaDataObjectValue() const »
```

etc ...

if I add the -fPIC option only for my code, and not for compiling the static libraries that it uses, I still get the error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

even if the qmake_cxxflags -fPIC is added.

what am I doing wrong ?*
(I put the Make file here in case it helps: https://github.com/pdeman/mevislabFetalMRI/blob/master/Makefile.CHUVTools.Release )

Comment: Well you have to compile itk with `-fPIC`; otherwise you can't use it to build a `.so`; but it sounds like you are missing `-lITKCommon` in the link for your library?

Comment: no -lITKCommon is present in the make file in LIBS variable. I recompiled ITK using -fPIC but I still get the same error

Comment: could it be a problem with the order of the linked libraries ?

Comment: See my answer - the problem is in the order of the linked libraries, and I've got a suggestion as to how to solve it in this case with minimal work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Makefile, I have a chance of debugging the issue.

The LIBS links in ITKCommon-4.13, so that's correct; it's needed to resolve `typeinfo for itk::MetaDataObjectBase`; which is being requested by `libITKIOGDCM-4.13`.

the LIBS line contains:

```
-lITKIOSiemens-4.13 -lITKBiasCorrection-4.13 -lITKIOSpatialObjects-4.13 -lITKBioCell-4.13 -lITKIOStimulate-4.13 -lITKCommon-4.13 -lITKIOTIFF-4.13 -lITKDICOMParser-4.13 -lITKIOTransformBase-4.13 -litkdouble-conversion-4.13 -lITKIOTransformHDF5-4.13 -lITKEXPAT-4.13 -lITKIOTransformInsightLegacy-4.13 -lITKFEM-4.13 -lITKIOTransformMatlab-4.13 -litkgdcmcharls-4.13 -lITKIOVTK-4.13 -litkgdcmCommon-4.13 -lITKIOXML-4.13 -litkgdcmDICT-4.13 -litkjpeg-4.13 -litkgdcmDSED-4.13 -lITKKLMRegionGrowing-4.13 -litkgdcmIOD-4.13 -lITKLabelMap-4.13 -litkgdcmjpeg12-4.13 -litklbfgs-4.13 -litkgdcmjpeg16-4.13 -lITKMesh-4.13 -litkgdcmjpeg8-4.13 -lITKMetaIO-4.13 -litkgdcmMEXD-4.13 -litkminc2-4.13 -litkgdcmMSFF-4.13 -litknetlib-4.13 -litkgdcmopenjp2-4.13 -litkNetlibSlatec-4.13 -litkgdcmsocketxx-4.13 -lITKniftiio-4.13 -litkgdcmuuid-4.13 -lITKNrrdIO-4.13 -lITKgiftiio-4.13 -lITKOptimizers-4.13 -litkgtest-4.13 -lITKOptimizersv4-4.13 -litkgtest_main-4.13 -lITKPath-4.13 -litkhdf5 -litkpng-4.13 -litkhdf5_cpp -lITKPolynomials-4.13 -lITKIOBioRad-4.13 -lITKQuadEdgeMesh-4.13 -lITKIOBMP-4.13 -lITKSpatialObjects-4.13 -lITKIOBruker-4.13 -lITKStatistics-4.13 -lITKIOCSV-4.13 -litksys-4.13 -lITKIOGDCM-4.13 -litktestlib-4.13 -lITKIOGE-4.13 -litktiff-4.13 -lITKIOGIPL-4.13 -lITKTransform-4.13 -lITKIOHDF5-4.13 -lITKTransformFactory-4.13 -lITKIOImageBase-4.13 -litkv3p_netlib-4.13 -lITKIOIPL-4.13 -litkvcl-4.13 -lITKIOJPEG-4.13 -lITKVideoCore-4.13 -lITKIOLSM-4.13 -lITKVideoIO-4.13 -lITKIOMesh-4.13 -litkvnl-4.13 -lITKIOMeta-4.13 -litkvnl_algo-4.13 -lITKIOMINC-4.13 -lITKVNLInstantiation-4.13 -lITKIOMRC-4.13 -lITKVTK-4.13 -lITKIONIFTI-4.13 -lITKWatersheds-4.13 -lITKIONRRD-4.13 -litkzlib-4.13 -lITKIOPNG-4.13 -lITKznz-4.13
```

Link resolution will happen, by default from left-to-right, which means that because the reference to `ITKCommon-4.13` happens before the reference to `ITKIOGDCM-4.13`, the typeinfo does not get resolved.

There are two solutions to this - the first one is to determine the link dependency order of all the libraries and sort them in reverse order. I don't know enough about the dependencies in the libraries to even come close to suggesting an order that might work, considering the number of libraries that are referenced here - it's got all the hallmarks of linking the kitchen sink.

The second solution is to wrap all the link options in a linker flag which says to treat all these files together for link purposes. It will probably slow down the link, but it guarantees that out-of-order or cross-dependencies will be resolved.

At the start of the list of `-l` items for ITK libraries, you add the option:-

```
-Wl,--start-group
```

and at the end of the list of `-l` items for ITK libraries, you add the option:-

```
--Wl,--end-group
```

so, to abbreviate the `LIBS` line, it would look somewhat like (the ellipsis indicates missing text):

```
-Wl,--start-group -lITKIOSiemens-4.13 … -lITKznz-4.13 -Wl,--end-group
```

Comment: thanks, it solves many of the problems, I now have this error: gdcm::System::GetCurrentModuleFileName() » :
gdcmSystem.cxx:(.text+0xc90) : undefined reference to « dladdr », I muss add a library in the link I guess

Comment: I added -ldl and it seems to work. thanks a lot.
I have one last question, could it be possible to change my qmake files, .pri and .pro, in order to don't have to modify my make file after. is there any qmake option to set the -Wl,--start-group, -Wl,--stop-group ?

Comment: As your `.pri` file in the project you reference in your question contains explicit `-l…` items in the `unix:LIBS` section, I would suspect you just need to add it to the start and end of that option list to get them to link in correctly.

Comment: perfect ! Thanks a lot !